# EF: DBContext in a wrapper object?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm having an issue with wrappers created to connect a UI layer with a data layer. Using EF 5 in each wrapper object I initialize with something such as :

```
Public Class Person
    Dim db As New db.Contex
    Dim _person As db.Person

 Public Sub New(ByVal PID As Guid)
    _person = (from p in db.people where p.ID = PID)  
End Sub

 Public Sub Save()
    db.SaveChanges() 
End Sub
```

The above code was causing caching issues in that the datastore would be updated with the proper values but when calling the Person again the old data was being returned. The fix i used to this issue was:

```
 Public Sub New(ByVal PID As Guid)
        db.Entry(db.Leads.Find(PID)).Reload()
        _person = db.People.Find(PID)
    End If
End Sub
```

While this does resolve the issue by forcing it to reload the object, it seems that this is a work-around and not a true fix. Can someone point out what i am doing wrong that is causing the incorrect data to be returned by EF?

An example issue would be as follows:

```
Dim tmpPerson as New Person(SomeValue)
tmpPerson.SomeParam = NewValue
tmpPerson.Save()

Dim tmpPerson_1 as New Person(SomeValue)
tmpPerson.SomeParam -> will display old value, not new value
```